# Internal Server Error, status=500 - getHibernateTemplate().delete(entity)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my Springboot application , when calling deleteoneXTwo() I get 
`There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Removing a detached instance .....entities OneXTwo#1`

Below is my code -

```
@Repository
public class OneXTwoDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements OneXTwoDao {

    public OneXTwoDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteoneXTwo() {
        getHibernateTemplate().setCheckWriteOperations(false);
        OneXTwo oneXTwo = (OneXTwo) getHibernateTemplate().get(OneXTwo.class, 1);
        getHibernateTemplate().delete(oneXTwo);
    }
}
```

-

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"ro"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"ro"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ro"})
public class BoostrapModules {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BoostrapModules.class);
    }


            /*
            USE FOR SESSION FACTORY
             */
                @Autowired
                private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

                @Bean
                public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
                    if (entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class) == null) {
                        throw new NullPointerException("factory is not a hibernate factory");
                    }
                    return entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
                }
}
```

Comment: Corrected the Question title and formatted the code for more readability.

Comment: You are removing not-manaded (anymore) entity in managed context